# Get audio input stream from a locale file on android

Tags: android

I am trying to get the audio input stream from a file in the local file system on an android device.

This is so that i can use this library to show a wave form for the audio file.

https://github.com/newventuresoftware/WaveformControl/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/newventuresoftware/waveformdemo/MainActivity.java#L125

The example in the project uses rawResource like so

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jinglebells);
```

This input stream is later converted into byte array and passed to somewhere that uses it to paint a wave picture and sound.

however when I did

```
InputStream is = new InputFileSystem(new File(filePath));
```

But this does not seem to work properly. The image generated is wrong, and the sound played is nothing like what the file actually is.

This is the body of the function in that library that gets the input stream and convert it into byte arrays.

```
private short[] getAudioSample() throws IOException {
    // If i replace this part with new FileInput(new File(filePath))
    // the generated "samples" from it does not work properly with the library.
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jinglebells);
    byte[] data;
    try {
        data = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
    ShortBuffer sb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
    short[] samples = new short[sb.limit()];
    sb.get(samples);
    return samples;
}
```

The sound file that I would like to get processed and pass to that library is created by a MediaRecorder with the following configurations

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including the code that uses `new File(filePath)`, and a complete explanation of what "does not seem to work properly" means.

Comment: I basically need to get the audio input stream from a file.

Comment: Is the file located in the resources directory or are you downloading it?

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani The file is created by a media recorder. So it is already inside the local file system (Not downloaded, not in resource either). I can play it correctly with a MediaPlayer without any issues. I just need to get the "audio input stream" of it and feed it to that library.

Comment: How are you obtaining the filePath and what is the exact error then?

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani There aren't any errors. By feeding FileInputStream into that particular library. The image / sound generated is just incorrect. The sound is white noise, and image is just a rectangle. But when the same file is played by mediaplayer it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically that library requires PCM samples. Using that 3gp FileInputStream generated by MediaRecorder directly is not gonna cut it.

What I did is to use MediaExtractor and MediaCodec to convert the 3gp audio data into PCM samples by samples. and then it is fed into that library. Then everything worked =)

The logic in encoding audio data can be almost directly taken from here [this awesome github repo](https://github.com/taehwandev/MediaCodecExample/blob/master/src/net/thdev/mediacodecexample/decoder/AudioDecoderThread.java#L169)